# Align text and font awesome icon while floating to left and right

Tags: html, css

So I got a problem that I've pulled my hair out over.

I am trying to have my text and font-awesome icon on the same height level, while the text is floated to the left, and the icon floated to the right.

But what i am getting is this:

[image: image1]

My code below

HTML

```
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s12">
                    <center>
                    <span class="account-information-licenses" style="font-size: 18px !important; text-align: center !important;">Licenses</span>
                  </center>
                  <span aria-label="Drivers License" data-balloon-pos="right">
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="float: right; color: #caeaa3 !important; font-size: 15px !important;"></i> 
                    <span class="account-information-driver-license" style="float: left; vertical-align: middle">Drivers License</span></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

CSS for rows/etc is materialize css.

Anyways this has been making me pull my hair out since it's so simple and it feels like i've tried everything.

Hope someone here can take a look at this with a fresh pair of eyes.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What you can do is put both in the container and vertically align items in centre in that container. And another piece of advice is don't use `!important` too much.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you wanted !? Let me know! if this works.**

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: coral;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2> LICENSES </h2>
  <div class="item"> Drivers License <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2C6.486 2 2 6.486 2 12s4.486 10 10 10 10-4.486 10-10S17.514 2 12 2zm-1.999 14.413-3.713-3.705L7.7 11.292l2.299 2.295 5.294-5.294 1.414 1.414-6.706 6.706z"></path></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

I used [Boxicons](https://boxicons.com/) you can choose icons library of your own choice the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

im sorry if this is not exactly how you wanted it but do you want it like this? (edit: i just realized you had it in a card, im so sorry)

```
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s12">
                    <center>
                    <span class="p" style="float: right;font-size: 18px !important; text-align: center !important;">Licenses</span>
                  </center>
                  <span aria-label="Drivers License" data-balloon-pos="right">
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="float: right; color: #caeaa3 !important; font-size: 15px !important;"></i> 
                    <span class="account-information-driver-license" style="float: left; vertical-align: middle">Drivers License</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

i made your licenses thing float to the opposite side, did you want it to be closer together?

Comment: I want the licenses in the middle.